# i want to display addition of textbox id=ttlpw and id=tplpw in id=twork.but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i want to add the first and second function value in third function.and i am using this third function value to display on one textbox.

i have tried to directly add the function and get the result but it doesnt work
i tried different function like onkeydown, onkeypress etc.

```js
//first function
function first() {
  var tt = parseInt(document.getElementById("divi").value);
  var pp = parseInt(document.getElementById("npt").value)
  var tl = parseInt(document.getElementById("tlpw").value)
  document.getElementById("ttlpw").value = tt * pp * tl;


}
//second function  
function second() {
  var tt = parseInt(document.getElementById("npp").value);
  var pp = parseInt(document.getElementById("plpw").value)
  var tl = parseInt(document.getElementById("nob").value)
  document.getElementById("tplpw").value = tt * pp * tl;
}

//third function

function third() {
  X = first();
  Y = second();
  document.getElementById("twork").value = x + y;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="npt" name="npt" onkeyup="first()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="npp" name="npp" onkeyup="second()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="tlpw" name="tlpw" onkeyup="first()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="plpw" name="plpw" onkeyup="second()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="divi" name="divi" onkeyup="first()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="nseb" name="nseb" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="nob" name="nob" onkeyup="second()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="ttlpw" name="ttlpw" " onkeyup="third() "   
     class="form-control " />
             <input type="text " id="tplpw " name="tplpw "" onkeyup="third()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="twork" name="twork" class="form-control" />
```

> This code does not give the addition of the value. I am expecting addition of x+y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- Your functions `first()` and `second()` print the value, but they don't actually return those values.
- On top of that, you have superfluous/random `"` characters and *space* characters which cause your inputs to not behave as expected.
- Finally, you assign `X` and `Y` and then try to add `x` and `y`, but Javascript is **case sensitive** so the addition tries to add two *undefined values*.

In the below snippet (click Show to see it) I fixed all of that, and I added placeholders so at least we have some indication of what we are typing into.

As a last note, it looks like **`cname`** and **`nseb`** are not being used anywhere, also they do not have a keyup event like most of the others.

It still looks a bit messy to me; I hope it makes more sense to you.

```js
// Give all inputs a placeholder
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   inputs[i].placeholder = inputs[i].id;
}

function first() {
  var tt = parseInt(document.getElementById("divi").value);
  var pp = parseInt(document.getElementById("npt").value);
  var tl = parseInt(document.getElementById("tlpw").value);
  var value = tt * pp * tl;
  document.getElementById("ttlpw").value = value;
  return value;
}

function second() {
  var tt = parseInt(document.getElementById("npp").value);
  var pp = parseInt(document.getElementById("plpw").value)
  var tl = parseInt(document.getElementById("nob").value)
  var value = tt * pp * tl;
  document.getElementById("tplpw").value = value;
  return value;
}

function third() {
  var x = first();
  var y = second();
  document.getElementById("twork").value = x + y;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="npt" name="npt" onkeyup="first()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="npp" name="npp" onkeyup="second()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="tlpw" name="tlpw" onkeyup="first()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="plpw" name="plpw" onkeyup="second()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="divi" name="divi" onkeyup="first()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="nseb" name="nseb" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="nob" name="nob" onkeyup="second()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="ttlpw" name="ttlpw" onkeyup="third()" class="form-control " />
<input type="text" id="tplpw" name="tplpw" onkeyup="third()" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="twork" name="twork" class="form-control" />
```

---

***Update:***

If I understand your need correctly, instead of doing `onkeyup="first()"` and `onkeyup="second()"`, try changing them all to use `onkeyup="third()"`. `third()` will call both the other functions, each of which will show their outcome, and then `third()` will show the sum of both.

Here is a new snippet that will do that. I also removed `cname` and `nseb`, and rearranged the order of inputs so they actually make sense.

```js
// Give all inputs a placeholder
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].placeholder = inputs[i].id;
}

function first() {
  var tt = parseInt(document.getElementById("divi").value);
  var pp = parseInt(document.getElementById("npt").value);
  var tl = parseInt(document.getElementById("tlpw").value);
  var value = tt * pp * tl;
  document.getElementById("ttlpw").value = value;
  return value;
}

function second() {
  var tt = parseInt(document.getElementById("npp").value);
  var pp = parseInt(document.getElementById("plpw").value)
  var tl = parseInt(document.getElementById("nob").value)
  var value = tt * pp * tl;
  document.getElementById("tplpw").value = value;
  return value;
}

function third() {
  var x = first();
  var y = second();
  document.getElementById("twork").value = x + y;
}
```

```css
div { width: 240px; text-align: right; }
input { width: 40px; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="npt" name="npt" onkeyup="third()" /> *
  <input type="text" id="divi" name="divi" onkeyup="third()" /> *
  <input type="text" id="tlpw" name="tlpw" onkeyup="third()" /> =
  <input type="text" id="ttlpw" name="ttlpw" onkeyup="third()" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="npp" name="npp" onkeyup="third()" /> *
  <input type="text" id="nob" name="nob" onkeyup="third()" /> *
  <input type="text" id="plpw" name="plpw" onkeyup="third()" /> =
  <input type="text" id="tplpw" name="tplpw" onkeyup="third()" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="twork" name="twork" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Mr. Peter what to do to get the addition of ttlpw and tplpw while value of the same is getting changed.Thank you!.

Comment: cname and nseb is actually need not  to use.

Comment: i really appreciate you.

Comment: If it helped, please consider voting and/or accepting the answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You need that functions `first` and `second` to return the value:

```
function first () {
  ...
  return tt * pp * tl
}
```

Comment: function first()
          {
               var tt = parseInt(document.getElementById("npp").value);
  var pp = parseInt(document.getElementById("plpw").value)
   var tl = parseInt(document.getElementById("nob").value)
  document.getElementById("tplpw").value = tt * pp * tl;
              return tt * pp * tl;
              
          }

Comment: but it does not gives any value

Comment: Are you sure `tt`, `pp` and `tl` have the right value and are the same type?

Comment: yes, they all are an integer and first and second function value are geting printed on ttlpw and tplpw

Comment: once the value is printed on ttlpw and tplpw i want to add these value and print on twork textbox at same time